# Remove _id from JSON sub array mongoose result

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a simple piece of code that retrieves a user's pantry from the MongoDB database. The pantry is an array of ingredients. I can retrieve the array of ingredients but each entry has an _id key:value pair that I don't want.

For example:

```
User.findOne({email:userEmail}, 'pantry', function(err,userPantry){
  console.log(userPantry);
})
```

Will give me

```
[{
  _id: tt34h7uhgt4ngu4hg,
  quantity:1,
  name:'beef'
}]
```

I am aware if I added `'-_id'` to the above code then it will remove the `_id`value but that is only to the root object which is the user how do I apply the same logic to remove it from the pantry array.

I'd rather make the database do the work then do a horrible foreach loop and remove it in the code.

Comment: have you tried `'-pantry._id'` ?

Comment: @Veeram that's incredibly obvious but it works. If you put as answer I will accept. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. I'll give it a little bit more time before posting it as solution as this will give others to look for duplicates which I was not able to locate.